# Recommended Minimum Android App SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I am making an android app, and am wondering what the industry's thoughts are on supporting older android versions like GingerBread and FroYo. Should a developer like me take the extra step to make my app compatible with those older versions, or are they obsolete? I am speaking in terms of the market in 2014.

Increasing my minimum SDK version opens up some more APIs, so which option should I pick, compatibility or APIs and features?

Comment: Complementary reference: Android source docs provide a list of: [Codename, Version, and API level/NDK release](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Most of the Android devices are above the Gingerbread level. But there are still a decent number of those devices out there.  You, as a developer, must decide if the number of users who would potentially download your app for those versions of Android is worth the level of effort in developing the app for those versions.   For the past year, both companies I've worked at have begun to work on 4.0 and above only and have forsaken the lower versions.

To get the current information on what the ecosystem looks like for Android, check out [Google's dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/)

As I write this comment, Gingerbread and below is around 15% of the total population.

**2019 UPDATE:** [Google's dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/) states that only 0.2% of Android users are running Gingerbread (Android 2.3). Around 3% are using Jelly Bean (Android 4.1/4.2/4.3), and 7.6% are running KitKat (Android 4.4).

Generally, companies target a minimum version of KitKat, or SDK 19, for new endeavors. For personal projects, we usually choose Lollipop, or SDK 21, as it brings a number of improvements to the table, such as improved build times.

Answer (score 42):

**[2020 UPDATE]** You need to base on Android **[Pie Chart](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)** . It is always updated.

here's the link of the dash board:

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: This is the only "correct" answer as:
1. It is not an opinion
2. It will always remain current

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer that won't get outdated with the pass of years. Having the visibility of what's the usage of each version, in the moment you consult that website is gold.

Comment: Further 2020 Update: On Aug 24, 2020 Google provided an email stating, "This is a reminder that starting November 2, 2020, updates to apps and games on Google Play will be required to target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher. After this date, the Play Console will prevent you from submitting new app bundles and APKs with a targetSdkVersion less than 29. ... This will not impact your existing listing on the Play Store." [Target API level requirements for the Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk)

Answer (score 20):

### For the record - 2020 April

If you look at the comments, they usually set the min level to 19 since years ago. Right now, it is nonsense (also, some comments are obsolete).

We are looked at the statistics of Google, and they say, "+10% of the devices are KitKat or lower. However, it's tough (if any) to find a company that sells phones for Kitkat.

So, why Kitkat 19 is still popular? Because old smartphones simply don't go away (and they aren't updated).

Then, technically 10% of the market uses  Kitkat or lower but **that information is mostly useless**

**From then 10%, how many of them will install your application? Or any new application?**. I know a lot of people that are happy with their old-and-rusty phone, but they only use for making calls and watch youtube/browser internet.   So, usually, the lower 10% is not part of our target market or the target market of anybody.

Twitter said about it:

- minSdkVersion · Nov 7, 2016 19
- minSdkVersion Apr 23, 2018 21
- minSdkVersion Dec 9, 2019 23

When Twitter says API=23, then Twitter is ignoring 25% of the market. It is a huge number. But again, this number means nothing without analysis. Twitter decided that this number is moot because, of the 25% of the users that use an old phone, they are not really in its market share, i.e., people that don't use Twitter on their phones using an application.

So, for the record and as for April 2020.

- API = 19 who are you pleasing?  Remember, we are 4 years later in comparison with Twitter.
- API = 21 is a moderated number.
- API = 23 sounds like a rational number.

For example, I run a windows server, and the default browser is Internet Explorer. Do you know how Internet Explorer works in the real world? It doesn't!. It works with google and a few sites, but everything else is broken.    And still, developers "support" internet explorer because of the non-existence 6.97% market share (the users exist, but they are not everybody users but intranet users).

Now, if your application is for a government/public interest, then we should stick with the standard or official procedure, and sometimes it could be around API 15 or 16.

Answer (score 15):

For those who are looking for an opinion to refer to, [@minSdkVersion](https://twitter.com/minsdkversion) updates their Twitter account when they deem it appropriate to start using a higher minimum SDK version. They claim

> The minimum SDK version for the practical, rational developer.

As others have mentioned, it's also worth checking the [Android distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform). The full platform version disribution can be found in Android Studio's **Create New Project wizard**.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE JULY 2022**

This is what Android Studio shows before creating a new Project.

[image: Chart extracted from Android Studio]

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't realize they tucked this info away in Android Studio... It also has a nice summary of features added in that API level.

Comment: Thanks @Duveral !!! Is there an online version of this graphic generated / updated anywhere? My favorite answer until very recently (answer from Basil Mariano, where you could see this information in this Google's link https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html ) is not showing a Pie Chart anymore :( And I wouldn't like to create a new project in Android Studio every time I need to think if I should / can afford to raise the minSdkVersion.

Comment: Nevermind, it's really easy to see this information in Android Studio. And it doesn't require to create a new project and leave the current open project. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

I'm a developer myself. I would look into this from multiple point of view and I would use several factors to begin a project with a particular sdk as minimum.

Beside the chart, that Google is kind enough to publish, which is really helpful and informative and i believe it represents devices around the world.

These are the factors I would take under consideration:

1. What's my app all about? What kind of people and what kind of age range would attract. Young people tend to keep their gadgets up-to-date.
2. In which country I'm going to release my app? Not all countries have the same mainstream when it comes to technology.
3. Does the minimum sdk affects the time or the resources that are going to be used in the app? If having a high sdk as minimum is inversely proportional with the time and the struggle my developers would face in order to make everything compatible, then I would choose a higher sdk, even if I have to exclude a small proportion of users. Let's face it, this is 2016. Technology is running faster than light. Releasing early really matters. In the other hand, if it really doesn't affect that much, then just choose a version that covers most devices.
4. Security matters as well. Everyday new issues are being patched. Newer version is more secure.
5. If the idea is powerful, than I would choose as higher as I could. People will follow. Is the truth.
6. Many functionalities are being deprecated. And usually in older versions. Upgrading from those can be hell.

Can't think of anything else. But if you want my opinion, I would choose API 19 as minimum.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

There were only few (~10) percent of users with Gingerbread to download our application from Play Store, so we have decided not to support it anymore. It was about 7 months ago. Froyo and Honeycomb are dead for much longer time.

We would go with Android 4.0 (API 14) as minimum for new projects. There is no real benefit from supporting older version unless you are forced to do so (client requested it, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Note the new directive from Google around the dropping of support for ICS (sdk 14 and 15). Recommended course of action is to set your minimum to 16. See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-play-services-discontinuing.html

Note that existing apps will continue to work ok.