# Selecting minimum android verion

Tags: android-version, minimum-requirements

I wanted to develop an application. What shall I consider to select my target android version (minimum version requirement)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Minimum Android App SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441178/recommended-minimum-android-app-sdk)

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="21"
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    />
```

you can use like this in AndroidManifest.xml